# How can I pass a prop in componentWillMount from application level state after connect() function run?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

This is my `homepage.js`

```js
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchGames } from '../actions';
import GameRowItem from './GameRowItem';

class Homepage extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchGames({this.props.userInfo});
  }

  renderRow(game) {
    return <GameRowItem game={game} />;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.games}
          renderItem={this.renderRow}
          keyExtractor={(game, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const games = _.map(state.games, (val, uid) => {
    return { ...val, uid };
  });
  return {
    games,
    userInfo: state.auth.userInfo
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchGames })(Homepage);
```

I want to pass a prop to my action after `connect()` function runs. Because I need my application level state and if I can't reach them before `componentWillMount()` function runs, I can't fetch my games properly...

I know I told mixed everything and it is diffucult to understand. Even so I hope someone understand me.

Comment: use componentDidMount instead componentWillMount

Comment: Is that `prop` not available by the time when it executes the componentWillMount ?

Answer (score 0):

If the props data is available when the component is initialized then you should better use `componentDidMount`.

If props data is available async after the initialization of the component, then you can use `componentWillReceiveProps` method which will be called every time whenever a prop is received from the parent component.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated and should no longer be used. `componentDidUpdate` should be used instead, or, in rare cases, `getDerivedStateFromProps`. Read the [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) for more info.